# File does not exist maatwebsite/excel laravel export from view

Tags: laravel, image, maatwebsite-excel

Tried to export an excel file through a Laravel blade but the issue exists when trying to add an image that is from external link not the same server (it's from google storage) **the image is accessible through browser**

The error is:

***PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception File URL does not exist***

Also, tried to get base64 and also didn't work

```
        $type = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

        didn't work <img src='{{$url}}' style="height: 20px;" height="100px">
        didn't work <img src='{{$base64}}' style="height: 20px;" height="100px">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786609/phpspreadsheet-how-do-i-place-a-image-from-link-into-my-excel-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by temporally download the image into the server and use the path to the image on the server.

Comment: I am managing to get the drawing to work when exporting to PDF but not when exporting to excel. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should not use the full  **url** instead, you may use the **path** to the image file.
supose your image file url is `example.com/assets/images/my-image.jpg`,
then you should use `assets/images/my-image.jpg`
for example this is how I did it in my blade view using `laravel excel`:

```
  <td>
       <img width="70" src="assets/images/my-image.jpg" alt="">
  </td>
```

In fact, I just mentioned the relative path without the full url and it wored like a charm.